# Connection reset by 10.0.0.8 port 22 while on local LAN

Tags: pi-3

I am trying to setup my new PI without a monitor as the display does not seem to go blank after display welcome screen.  I have enabled "ssh" by creating a file under the root folder (boot/.ssh) and the pi also prompts with a warning that ssh is being enabled.  Hence tried connecting to pi from ssh after finding the IP it is bound to after connecting to local router.
The output of ssh is attached below and requesting guidance to resolve the issue.
FYI, I am connecting to pi through iMAC running latest version of OSX.

```
Jayaramans-iMac:~ jay$ ssh -v -l pi 10.0.0.8
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.8 [10.0.0.8] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Volumes/home/Users/jay/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Volumes/home/Users/jay/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Volumes/home/Users/jay/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Volumes/home/Users/jay/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Volumes/home/Users/jay/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Volumes/home/Users/jay/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Volumes/home/Users/jay/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Volumes/home/Users/jay/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.0.0.8:22 as 'pi'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by 10.0.0.8 port 22
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the listing the Mac seems to be trying to connect to the Pi, but is unable to authenticate.

Normally this would prompt for a password, after checking other options, unless PasswordAuthentication is disabled in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

I haven't actually used this for years, because I set up public/private keys as described in `man ssh`

The `identity file /Volumes/home/Users/jay/.ssh/` indicates the directory being searched is mounted on the Mac, although the directory looks unusual, and does not match any normal Pi directory.

Comment: the log is from the mac from which I am trying to connect to PI.  As mentioned i have not yet been able to connect to pi successfully since the purchase :(

Answer (score 0):

Which partition did you add the .ssh file? There are two. It should go in the boot partition, not in the boot directory/folder on the second partition.

Not saying it's wrong but why did you name the .ssh rather than just ssh?

Comment: my apologies, I posted my comment in the subsequent response from Milliways.  The above output is from the command `ssh -v -l pi 10.0.0.8` that I ran on my iMac trying to connect to the PI through SSH.

Answer (score 0):

The following is just a wild guess and I haven't tested if it will work.

If you had setup your public/private keys years ago, perhaps try to rename your old keys files and then regenerate new keys to see if that will work. Also, you may wanna check your ~/.ssh directory of your *pi* account if it may contain any file that invalids the process of SSH. If I encountered a problem like this, I would just rename the ~/.ssh directory of the *pi* account to see if the problem will get resolved.